# Submit form with JS on pressing enter but not when on autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've got a form with a custom submit button (not an input[type=submit]). I want the form to submit on pressing enter which the function below does, but it also submits on pressing enter to select a item from a autocomplete dropdown. How do I prevent it from submitting when selecting a autocomplete option?

```
submitForm.delegate('input','submit',function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 13) 
        submitForm.trigger('submit');
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put in a validation / completeness check

```
if (e.keyCode === 13 && submitForm.isComplete()) {
    submitForm.trigger('submit');
}
```

OR - revert back to a submit button for better semantics, what's the reason for not using it?

Comment: thanks, the submit button design is impossible to render as a normal input. Just discovered that having a hidden submit button works as well